# Compare counts in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to compare two results of queries of the same table, by checking theresulting row count, but Postgres doesn't support column aliases in the where clause.

```
select id from article where version=1308
and exists(
select count(ident) as count1 from artprice AS p1
where p1.valid_to<to_timestamp(1586642400000) or p1.valid_from>to_timestamp(1672441199000)
  and p1.article=article.id
  and p1.count1=(select count(ident) from artprice where article=article.id)
)
```

I also cannot use aggregate functions in the where clause, so

```
select id from article where version=1308
and exists(
select count(ident) as count1 from artprice AS p1
where p1.valid_to<to_timestamp(1586642400000) or p1.valid_from>to_timestamp(1672441199000)
  and p1.article=article.id
  and p1.count(ident)=(select count(ident) from artprice where article=article.id)
)
```

also doesn't work. Any ideas?

EDIT:
What I want to get are articles where every article price is outside of a valid range defined by validFrom andValidTo.

Comment: Can you please share your tables' structures, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for that sample?

Comment: So you want to retrieve the id-s from table article, where the related artprice has the same id and they have the same number of indents?

BTW, did you try the `group by` and `having` clauses ? Maybe you only need to take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: I don't understand what you want but what is sure is that exists(select count(ident) from ... always return true so it's useless.

Comment: In addition to the wrong usage of the exists() you will also have to add parentheses around your `OR` condition so that it actually works the way you expect it to work: `where (p1.valid_to<to_timestamp(1586642400000) or p1.valid_from>to_timestamp(1672441199000)) and ...`

Answer (score 1):

Aggregates are not allowed in WHERE clause, but there's HAVING clause for them.

> EDIT: What I want to get are articles where every article price is outside of a valid range defined by validFrom andValidTo.

I think that [`bool_or()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) would be a good fit here when combined with [range operations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html):

```
SELECT article.id
FROM Article AS article
JOIN ArtPrice AS price ON price.article = article.id
WHERE article.version = 1308
GROUP BY article.id
HAVING NOT bool_or(tsrange(price.valid_from, price.valid_to)
                   && tsrange(to_timestamp(1586642400000),
                              to_timestamp(1672441199000)))
```

This reads as "...those having not any price tsrange overlap with given tsrange".

Postgresql also supports the [SQL OVERLAPS operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html):

```
(price.valid_from, price.valid_to) OVERLAPS (to_timestamp(1586642400000),
                                             to_timestamp(1672441199000))
```

As a note, it operates on half-open intervals `start <= time < end`.

Comment: Doesn't work with 9.2...

The statements is as follows:
Get all articles where every price is outside a valid range, defined by validFrom and validTo.

Comment: I now changed the statement by negating the positive conditions:

Answer (score 1):

I now changed the statement by negating the positive conditions:

```
Select distinct article.id from Article article, ArtPrice price 
where 
(
  (article.version=?) 
  and 
  (
    (
      (
        (
          (not(price.valid_from>=?)) or (not(price.valid_to<=?))
        ) 
        and 
        (
          (not(price.valid_from<=?)) or (not(price.valid_to>=?))
        )
      ) 
      and 
      (
        (not(price.valid_to>=?)) or (not(price.valid_to<=?))
      )
    )
    and 
    (
      (not(price.valid_from>=?)) or (not(price.valid_from<=?))
    )
  )
) and article.id=price.article
```

Probably not the very elegant solution, but it works.

Comment: Wont this return `article.id` for articles with any 1 price range out of valid range, not all?

Comment: Could be a matter of opinion, but you can apply De Morgan's laws to remove the double NOTs: `(NOT x) OR (NOT y)` can be replaced with `NOT (x AND y)`. This then can be applied further, as `(NOT x) AND (NOT y)` can be replaced with `NOT (x OR y)`. Thus you could write `article.version = ? AND NOT ((p.valid_from >= ? AND p.valid_to <= ?) OR (p.valid_from <= ? AND p.valid_to >= ?) OR (p.valid_to >= ? AND p.valid_to <= ?) OR (p.valid_from >= ? AND p.valid_from <= ?)) ...`. The last 2 then can be replaced with `p.valid_to BETWEEN ? AND ?` and the same for *from*.